# Flattening a CGPath

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics

Simply put, I'm looking for an equivalent to NSBezierPath's `-bezierPathByFlatteningPath` that can be used on iOS. It doesn't matter to me whether this is a function dealing directly with a CGPath or a method on UIBezierPath, because the two can easily be converted back and forth. Neither the [CGPath Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html) nor the [UIBezierPath Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) indicate the presence of any such function or method.

Also: I'm aware of CGPath's `CGPathApply` function, and I lack both the time and the skill-set to implement my own flattening algorithm by iterating over the path's elements in a `CGPathApplierFunction`. I'm looking for an existing solution to this—an applier function, a category on UIBezierPath, etc. Surely one exists.

Comment: Using a `UIBezierPath`, does setting `path.flatness = 1` accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: Sadly, no, because as a drawing property, `flatness` only affects how the curve is rendered, not how it is stored.

Comment: Hmm... In that case, your best bet is probably to loop through all the points using `CGPathApply` and build a new path using the appropriate functions to get the flat effect.

Comment: That's the right idea, but it's exactly what I was hoping to avoid doing. [This person](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2010/Nov/msg00000.html) asked pretty much the exact same thing a couple years ago in the Apple Mailing Lists, but sadly stopped getting replies after [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2010/Nov/msg00004.html). I honestly might just scrap the plan that led me to need to do this in the first place, but for the sake of everyone who made "flatten cgpath" a suggested Google search, it'd still be great if someone out there had an answer to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erica Sadun provides a set of useful functions to deal with UIBezierPath and CGPathRef.

This code is used in [this book](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/book/ios-drawing-practical-uikit/id726298570?mt=11).

She does not provide an implementation of a CGPathRef flattening, but it can be easily done using functions that can be found here:
https://github.com/erica/iOS-Drawing/blob/master/C05/Quartz%20Book%20Pack/Bezier/BezierFunctions.m

Particulary, these functions will help discretize the non linear Bezier segments:

```
float CubicBezier(float t, float start, float c1, float c2, float end)
float QuadBezier(float t, float start, float c1, float end)
CGPoint CubicBezierPoint(CGFloat t, CGPoint start, CGPoint c1, CGPoint c2, CGPoint end);
CGPoint QuadBezierPoint(CGFloat t, CGPoint start, CGPoint c1, CGPoint end);
```

So basically, initialize an empty CGMutablePathRef, and for each CGPath element in the original path, either copy it if it's linear, or discretize it according to the degree of the Bezier segment.

You may also want to apply the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to remove unnecessary points.

You could also directly use: `- (NSArray *) interpolatedPathPoints` which returns an NSArray of points which can be used to build an approximation of the path. The algorithm is naive, so you have to simplify the result in the case, e.g , where a cubic Bezier path would be linear (if the control points are aligned); just as before, Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm does the job.

Here is what the actual discretization looks like. Code is not self contained, you'll have to use all dependencies.

```
- (NSArray *) interpolatedPathPoints
{
    NSMutableArray *points = [NSMutableArray array];
    BezierElement *current = nil;
    int overkill = 3;
    for (BezierElement *element in self.elements)
    {
        switch (element.elementType)
        {
            case kCGPathElementMoveToPoint:
            case kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint:
                [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:element.point]];
                current = element;
                break;
            case kCGPathElementCloseSubpath:
                current = nil;
                break;
            case kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint:
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_BEZIER_SAMPLES * overkill; i++)
                {
                    CGFloat percent = (CGFloat) i / (CGFloat) (NUMBER_OF_BEZIER_SAMPLES * overkill);
                    CGPoint p = CubicBezierPoint(percent, current.point, element.controlPoint1, element.controlPoint2, element.point);
                    [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
                }
                [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:element.point]];
                current = element;
                break;
            }
            case kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint:
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < NUMBER_OF_BEZIER_SAMPLES * overkill; i++)
                {
                    CGFloat percent = (CGFloat) i / (CGFloat) (NUMBER_OF_BEZIER_SAMPLES * overkill);
                    CGPoint p = QuadBezierPoint(percent, current.point, element.controlPoint1, element.point);
                    [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
                }
                [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:element.point]];
                current = element;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

Code belongs to Erica Sadun. See here for the complete implementation: https://github.com/erica/iOS-Drawing

Rob Napier also wrote about Bezier curves in [iOS 6 Pushing the limits](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/book/ios-6-programming-pushing/id584815085?mt=11), Chapter 26
Fancy Text Layout. He was not trying to flatten a full UIBezierPath, only one cubic Bezier path defined with four points, but really that's exactly the same thing (discretizing a Bezier path) 
Also, you may find this article interesting: http://robnapier.net/faster-bezier

Comment: This, while still less than ideal (the ideal being [an Apple-supplied API](http://www.openradar.me/15217701)), does a much better job of answering the original question in that it addresses discretization of non-linear path segments, so I've moved the checkmark over here.

Answer (score 1):

What you're basically looking to do is transform the path to replace all the curves and quadCurves to lines.  You can do this pretty painlessly with `CGPathApply` and wrap it in a category on `UIBezierPath`:

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

@interface UIBezierPath (Flatten)
- (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathByFlatteningPath;
@end

void __flattenBezierPath(void *target, const CGPathElement *element) {
    UIBezierPath *newPath = (__bridge UIBezierPath *)(target);

    switch (element->type) {
        case kCGPathElementMoveToPoint:
            [newPath moveToPoint:element->points[0]];
            break;

        case kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint:
            [newPath addLineToPoint:element->points[0]];
            break;

        case kCGPathElementCloseSubpath:
            [newPath closePath];
            break;

        case kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint:
            [newPath addLineToPoint:element->points[2]];
            break;

        case kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint:
            [newPath addLineToPoint:element->points[1]];
            break;
    }

}

@implementation UIBezierPath (Flatten)

- (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathByFlatteningPath
{
    UIBezierPath *newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGPathApply(self.CGPath, (__bridge void *)(newPath), __flattenBezierPath);
    return newPath;
}

@end
```

The effect can be seen below, where green is the original path, red is the path generated by this method, and yellow is the path using `setFlatness:MAXFLOAT`

[image: Different renderings of the bezier path]

Comment: This is a good answer, but you haven't provided a way to change the granularity of the approximation as can be done with `NSBezierPath`'s  `setDefaultFlatness:` method. This also treats all parts of the curve in the same way, when it should be breaking steeper parts of the curve into more pieces for a better approximation. Sorry to just abandon this question—I've kind of moved on from the issue myself, but just for good measure I've filed a radar (http://www.openradar.me/15217701) and marked this as the answer for now. :)

Comment: You're supposed to discretize the quadric and cubic Bezier curves into a succession of linear segments.. This is not a flattening function.